# C++ OpenCV do face recognition until camera is removed

Tags: c++, opencv

I´m using OpenCV for some face recognition stuff with a webcam. The thing is, whenever there is no camera installed, I get an exception. I handled that at the beginning with this code:

```
if (!realTime.isOpened())
{
    cout << "No webcam installed!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

realTime is an object of VideoCapture. So when I want to start the program with no webcam plugged in, I get a "No webcam installed" in the console.
But now I want the program to immediately stop whenever the webcam is plugged off. This seems to be really hard, cause my face recognition is in a while loop:

```
namedWindow("Face Detection", WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);

string trained_classifier_location = "C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

CascadeClassifier faceDetector;

faceDetector.load(trained_classifier_location);

vector<Rect> faces;

while (true)
{
    realTime.read(videoStream);


    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(videoStream, faces, 1.1, 4, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));



    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {

        Mat faceROI = videoStream(faces[i]);

        int x = faces[i].x;
        int y = faces[i].y;
        int h = y + faces[i].height;
        int w = x + faces[i].width;
        rectangle(videoStream, Point(x, y), Point(w, h), Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    imshow("Face Detection", videoStream);

    if (waitKey(10) == 27)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I also tried it with a try-catch-statement, but the exception is thrown at

Comment: "*But now I want the program to immediately stop whenever the webcam is plugged off.*" If OpenCV throws an exception, unhandled exception will immediately stop your program.

Comment: But the program crashes then, when i build and execute it, it tells me that FaceRecog.exe doesn't work anymore. I want to prevent that

Comment: why don't you catch the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of `read` (you should do that anyway). From the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1):

> The method/function combines VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call. This is the most convenient method for reading video files or capturing data from decode and returns the just grabbed frame. **If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the method returns false** and the function returns empty image (with cv::Mat, test it with Mat::empty()).

So:

```
bool valid_frame = false;
while (true)
{
    valid_frame = realTime.read(videoStream);
    if(!valid_frame) 
    { 
        std::cout << "camera disconnected, or no more frames in video file";
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```